# Form submits like ajax's not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I've got a form which checks the status in the db for the entered email. Problem is, whenever I do no fill in anything and hit enter, it 'refreshes' the page. When I try to refresh it myself, the following popup shows up: "Confirm Form Resubmission. The page that you're looking for used information that you entered. Returning to that page might cause any action you took to be repeated. Do you want to continue?".

The funny thing is that I do submit my form via Ajax. It works on any other page except for this one, which is kinda weird. I rechecked everything but I cannot find whatevers wrong.

**This is my form:**

```
<div class="content main container">
<div class="content main box">
<form method="post" id="checkStatForm" name="form">
<input type="email" class="fullwidth-input-field" name="email" placeholder="- fill in the email you registered with -" autocomplete="off" />
</form>

<input type="submit" class="button red" id="checkStatusNow" value="Check status" />

</div>
</div>
```

**And this is my javascript piece**

```
//Statuscheck
$(function() { 
    $("#checkStatusNow").click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "db-requests/db-statuscheck.php",
            data: $("#checkStatForm").serialize(),
            success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){   finishCheck(data,textStatus,jqXHR); }
        });
    });
});

function finishCheck( data , textStatus ,jqXHR ) {

    if ( data == "requiredFieldsStatusCheck" ) {
        $('#emptyField').fadeIn(500).show();
        $('#wrongEmailFormat').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#noPaymentReceived').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#awaitingProcessing').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#udidIsActivated').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#noEmailResults').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#betaIsActivated').fadeOut(300).hide();
    } 

    if ( data == "errorEmailFormatStatusCheck" ) {
        $('#wrongEmailFormat').fadeIn(500).show();
        $('#emptyField').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#noPaymentReceived').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#awaitingProcessing').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#udidIsActivated').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#noEmailResults').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#betaIsActivated').fadeOut(300).hide();
    } 

    if ( data == "noPaymentReceived" ) {
        $('#noPaymentReceived').fadeIn(500).show();
        $('#emptyField').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#wrongEmailFormat').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#awaitingProcessing').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#udidIsActivated').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#noEmailResults').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#betaIsActivated').fadeOut(300).hide();
    }

    if ( data == "paymentReceivedAwaitingProcessing" ) {
        $('#awaitingProcessing').fadeIn(500).show();
        $('#emptyField').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#wrongEmailFormat').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#noPaymentReceived').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#udidIsActivated').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#noEmailResults').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#betaIsActivated').fadeOut(300).hide();
    }

    if ( data == "udidIsActivated" ) {
        $('#udidIsActivated').fadeIn(500).show();
        $('#emptyField').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#wrongEmailFormat').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#noPaymentReceived').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#awaitingProcessing').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#noEmailResults').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#betaIsActivated').fadeOut(300).hide();
    }

    if ( data == "betaIsActivated" ) {
        $('#betaIsActivated').fadeIn(500).show();
        $('#emptyField').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#wrongEmailFormat').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#noPaymentReceived').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#awaitingProcessing').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#noEmailResults').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#udidIsActivated').fadeOut(300).hide();
    }

    if ( data == "noEntryFound" ) {
        $('#noEmailResults').fadeIn(500).show();
        $('#emptyField').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#wrongEmailFormat').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#noPaymentReceived').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#awaitingProcessing').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#udidIsActivated').fadeOut(300).hide();
        $('#betaIsActivated').fadeOut(300).hide();
    }
}
//End statuscheck
```

Anyone out here who knows what I'm doing wrong lol? Let me know if you need the 'db-statuscheck.php' file. I'm 100% sure that file's good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the form's `onsubmit` handler not a button click, and you need to return false or prevent default:

```
$("#checkStatForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "db-requests/db-statuscheck.php",
        data: $("#checkStatForm").serialize(),
        success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){   finishCheck(data,textStatus,jqXHR); }
    });
});
```

Now, submitting the form via the enter key will also be handled via ajax, not just the submit button click.

Answer (score 1):

Your "click" handler has to make sure that the default behavior of the `<input type=submit>` does not happen, because that default behavior is the ordinary submission of the `<form>`.

```
$("#checkStatusNow").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // <---- THIS
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "db-requests/db-statuscheck.php",
        data: $("#checkStatForm").serialize(),
        success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){   finishCheck(data,textStatus,jqXHR); }
    });
});
```

Purists would disagree, and I add this for completeness and not to provoke outrage, but an alternative would be to use a `<button type=button>` for instead of a "submit" input.

Answer (score 1):

Its trying to do "Submit" instead of an Ajax submit. Try to remove `type="submit"` and submit using Ajax.